# Python flask server runs on a different port first time

Tags: python, flask

As the question suggests, I have a small `python` flask app that runs on localhost and port `8083`. But when I run it first time using `python3 server.py` it first gives this output:

> Debug mode: off

- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

And when I press `CTRL+C` it runs on the correct port I defined without really quiting.

> Debug mode: off

- Running on http://0.0.0.0:8083/ (Press CTRL+C to quit

And this is my `server.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
# import linearregression
from os import path, walk


app.run()

PORT = 8083

# predicted_values = linearregression.runModel()

f = open("/home/jananath/Desktop/SLIIT/CDAP/2020_62/backends/banuka/banuka.txt", "r")
return_value = f.readline() # Write your logic to select any specific line or key value pair etc.
f.close()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    # return "Predicted Values - " + str(predicted_values)
    return str(return_value)

@app.route('/banuka')
def hi():
    return "Hi Jananath"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    extra_dirs = ['/home/jananath/Desktop/SLIIT/CDAP/2020_62/backends/banuka',]
    extra_files = extra_dirs[:]
    for extra_dir in extra_dirs:
        for dirname, dirs, files in walk(extra_dir):
            for filename in files:
                filename = path.join(dirname, filename)
                if path.isfile(filename):
                    extra_files.append(filename)   

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, extra_files=extra_files)
```

And **other thing is, I want to reload this server every time I do a change in this file or file mentioned in the path  `/home/jananath/Desktop/SLIIT/CDAP/2020_62/backends/banuka/banuka.txt`** can someone help me with these two issues?

Comment: You've got an extra `app.run()` up at the top. Try removing that.

Comment: Okay, now it is working thanks. Can you tell me how can watch for file changes and reload the server? I export FLASK_DEBUG=1 and it works locally, but when I do this inside a docker container it doesn't reload. I have even mounted volumes and even volumes are getting updated but app doesn't refresh.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with the reloading bit. Glad the other part is working now.